# R substitute on expression with assignment

Tags: r

Why do these two cases behave differently?

```
>substitute(c1<-100,list(c1=100))
100 <- 100
```

vs

```
> substitute(c1=100,list(c1=100))
[1] 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand help to `assignOps` operator `=` evaluates immediately. So the second expression is equivalent to `substitute(100,list(c1=100))`.
But you could take it in braces and the result is

```
> substitute({c1=100},list(c1=100))
{
    100 = 100
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the second expression interprets `c1 = 100` as saying the argument named `c1` of the function `substitute` should have value 100.

Comment: ok but even if I wrap it in I() it doesn't actually substitue it while for I(c1<-100) it does

Comment: Why do you think `I()` would do anything here?